# how to use restsharp web rest api

Tags: c#, json, api, restsharp

hi there i am new to rest api 
i build these api
https://dastanito.ir/test/ex2/api/storiesmaster/read.php
https://dastanito.ir/test/ex2/api/storiesmaster/read_one.php?id=60

i used requests lib in python and everything is ok

but i do not know how to use this with restsharp

```cs
  var client = new RestClient("https://dastanito.ir/test/ex2/api/storiesmaster/read.php");

            var request = new RestRequest("");

            var response = client.Post(request);
            MessageBox.Show(response.Content.ToString());
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on [RestSharp](http://restsharp.org) sample:

```
var client = new RestClient("https://dastanito.ir");   

var request = new RestRequest("test/ex2/api/storiesmaster/read.php", Method.GET);

// execute the request
IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
var content = response.Content; // raw content as string
```

Output:

```
{"StoriesMasters":[{"id":"2","story_code":"002a","master_code":"he3385_1"},{"id":"60","story_code":"001a","master_code":"he3385_1"},{"id":"3","story_code":"c57675","master_code":"ara3433_2"},{"id":"50","story_code":"d8885","master_code":"za76787_3"}]}
```

Comment: Thanks but when i check content  it is empty

Comment: Check the code now. I assumed that you need a POST method. I changed to GET.

Comment: thanks content.ToString() is this the output ? because when i used messageBox to show it is still return nothing

Comment: Yes -> response.Content. Make sure you use Method.GET in our request. You can also check response.StatusCode for any errors. I am getting 200 -> OK.

Comment: my  response.StatusCode is 0 :/

Comment: Check your RestSharp version in packages.json. Mine is 106.6.10.

Comment: mine is same as you ... i changed https to http and  it works!